# Saving an image with transparent background to webdav gives white background

Tags: java, image-processing, transparency, webdav, sardine

I am trying to save an image to a webdav folder by this method:

```
void saveToWebdav(final Sardine sardine, 
                  final InputStream inputStream, 
                  final int length) throws IOException {
          try{
                ImageIO.write(ImageIO.read(inputStream),
                                      "png",
                                      new File("check_before_webdav.png"));
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        InputStreamEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(inputStream, length);
        ((SardineImpl) sardine).put(url.toString(), entity, null, true);
    }
```

I am using sardine(https://code.google.com/p/sardine/) and in the above code, I save the image for testing purposes to my local.(the original image also has png extension, i am not changing it)

although both the original image and the one that I save just before sending to webdav has no background (transparent background), the resulting image has white background. any ideas why transparent background becomes white after writing to webdav?

Comment: No. You may want to compare the two files to find out what exactly changed.

Comment: Seems the webdav server modifies your files. As @JulianReschke suggests, compare the input with the original to figure out what's going on.